# Italian text extract from image with OpenCV and tessaract python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tesseract

I have tried this way to workaround:

```
from pytesseract import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('img.jpg')

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='')

# Displaying the extracted text
print(text[:-1])
```

But this code does not extract all the text.

Here is the output [output](https://easyupload.io/x5v0tc)

Comment: I bet the card holder isn't very happy about his id card being online

Comment: did you work around with this, how to extract all the text from image.